# how to merge rows with the same column in sql like this?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Table1: Factor_Name

```
ID NAME
1  A
2  A
3  B
```

Table2: Sample_Info

```
   ID   FACTOR_ID   INFO
   1    1           Sample_A
   2    2           Sample_B
   3    3           Sample_C
```

I want to merge the column in the 2 tables if the factor names are same in table1, this is the expected table:

Table1: Factor_Name

```
ID NAME
1  A
2  B
```

Table2: Sample_Info

```
   ID   FACTOR_ID   INFO
   1    1           Sample_A
   2    1           Sample_B
   3    2           Sample_C
```

How can I do that in mysql?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what is going on in your example.  It looks like you just removed the duplicate `NAME` values from `FACTOR_NAME` in your desired output, and then remapped `FACTOR_ID` in `Sample_Info`?  This doesn't exactly sound like merging two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to do this by first duplicating the tables you currently have:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Factor_Name_Temp as (SELECT * 
                                            FROM Factor_Name) 

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Sample_Info_Temp as (SELECT * 
                                            FROM Sample_Info)
```

Then, you're going to need to clear the contents of the existing tables.  You also appear to want to reset the id columns.  This could be slightly dangerous, depending on how many *other* tables reference these values.  But either way...

Then, insert the data from the 'temp' tables back into the original tables.  Leave off the id column if you're having them re-generated, otherwise this will choose the initial 'minimum' value (ie, there'll be gaps).

```
INSERT Factor_Name (id, name) 
SELECT MIN(id), name
FROM Factor_Name_Temp
GROUP BY name

INSERT Sample_Info (id, factor_id, info)
SELECT Sample_Info_Temp.id, Factor_Name.id, Sample_Info_Temp.info
FROM Sample_Info_Temp
JOIN Factor_Name_Temp
  ON Factor_Name_Temp.id = Sample_Info_Temp.factor_id
JOIN Factor_Name
  ON Factor_Name.name = Factor_Name_Temp.name
```

Don't forget to clean up after yourself!

(Statements untested - I lack a mySQL instance, and SQL Fiddle isn't completely conductive to this).